# Поворот экрана с MVP, Android, RxJava,

Tags: android, архитектура, rxjava, mvp

Best Practices в обработке смен конфигураций экрана во фрагменте при таком наборе: `MVP` и `RxJava` (`RxBindings` не юзаю, но если без него будет совсем худо- посмотрю, предпочтительнее без него)?

Например, есть приложение с лентой новостей. При первом запуске мы отсылаем запрос через `Retrofit`, получаем от него `Observable`, обрабатываем в презентере и по итогу дергаем методы у нашего фрагмента, во всех последующих открытиях фрагмента, используем данные из БД (Вся лента кэшируется при отправке запросов в сеть). Обновление ленты по сети только по нажатию кнопки и по перезаходу в приложение.

1) Может произойти такое, что презентер будет использовать методы фрагмента, когда его нет на экране. Как это предотвратить? Подумывал складывать все вызовы методов фрагмента презентером в какой-нибудь кэш и при появлении на экране фрагмента, все функции из этой очереди выполнять.

2) Как лучше делать: при каждом пересоздании фрагмента, пересоздавать и презентер тоже, или всегда иметь один неубиваемый экземпляр презентера для каждого фрагмента. Где тогда хранить эти презентеры и не будут ли тогда попадаться дубликаты?

Ради наглядности, приведу конкретные примеры из кода, как это реализовано **СЕЙЧАС**

**IShopsFragment.java**

```
public interface IShopsFragment {
    void showShops(List<Shop> shops);
    void showProgressIndicator(boolean show);
    void showError(boolean show);
    void showMessageNoInternetConnection();
}
```

**IShopsPresenter.java**

```
public interface IShopsPresenter {
    void loadShops();

    void onRefreshButClick();
    void onShopClick(Shop shop);

    void onCreateView();
    void onDestroyView();
}
```

**ShopsPresenter.java**

```
public class ShopsPresenter implements IShopsPresenter {

    private IShopsFragment fragment;
    private DataManager dataManager;
    private Realm realm;
    private static int fragmentOpens = 0;


    ShopsPresenter(IShopsFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        dataManager = DataManager.getInstance();
    }


    @Override
    public void loadShops() {
        fragment.showError(false);
        if(fragmentOpens > 1){
            loadShopsFromCache();
            return;
        }
        fragmentOpens++;
        fragment.showProgressIndicator(true);
        dataManager.loadShopsFromWeb()
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Shop>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        fragment.showProgressIndicator(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "onError() in loadShops()");
                        fragment.showMessageNoInternetConnection();
                        loadShopsFromCache();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Shop> shopsList) {
                        fragment.showShops(shopsList);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshButClick() {
        loadShops();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShopClick(Shop shop) {
        FragmentChanger.getInstance()
                .setFragment(ShopFragment.getInstance(shop))
                .needAddToBackStack(true)
                .changeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateView() {
        if(realm == null){
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if(realm != null){
            realm.close();
        }
    }

    private void loadShopsFromCache(){
        dataManager.loadShopsFromCache(realm)
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Shop>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        fragment.showProgressIndicator(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        fragment.showProgressIndicator(false);
                        fragment.showError(true);
                        Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "onError() in loadShopsFromCache()");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Shop> shopsList) {
                        Log.d(TESTING_TAG, "onNext() in loadShopsFromCache()");
                        if (shopsList.size() == 0) {
                            onError(new Throwable("Empty cache"));
                        }else {
                            fragment.showShops(shopsList);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**ShopsFragment.java**

```
public class ShopsFragment extends Fragment implements IShopsFragment {


    private View rootView;
    private Context context;
    IShopsPresenter presenter;
    private ImageView refreshIcon;

    public static ShopsFragment getInstance(){
        return new ShopsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("mytag", "onCreateView()");
        Log.d("mytag", "createCounter = " + createCounter);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.shops_fragment, container, false);
        context = rootView.getContext();
            presenter = new ShopsPresenter(this);
            presenter.onCreateView();
            presenter.loadShops();
        refreshIcon = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.refreshIcon);
        refreshIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.onRefreshButClick());
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void showShops(List<Shop> shops) {
        ShopsAdapter shopsAdapter = new ShopsAdapter(context, shops, this);
        ListView lvMain = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shopsList);
        lvMain.setAdapter(shopsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgressIndicator(boolean show) {
        RelativeLayout loadingLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingLayout);
        if(show){
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showError(boolean show) {
        RelativeLayout errorLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.errorLayout);
        if(show){
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessageNoInternetConnection() {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_loading_shops, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    presenter.onDestroyView();
    if(refreshIcon != null){
        refreshIcon = null;
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем есть отличная библиотека, чтобы жить без боли ЖЦ при mvp архитектуре. https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy
Сам использую в нескольких проектах, и всем советую.